# how to find element using regex inside the path in WebdriverIO framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverIO for automation and I use javascript for programming. I was getting error trying to find element matching a regex path. Could some one point me the right direction.

```
let patt = 'Total \([0 - 9]+\)/g';
    console.log("********** FOUND *************" + $("//div[contains(text(),'" + patt + "')]").getText());
}
```

Element looks like this

```
<div _ngcontent-mvr-c11="" class="centered bar-text margin ng-star-inserted">Total (0)</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
can't call getText on element with selector "//div[contains(text(),'Total ([0 - 9]+)/g')]" because element wasn't found
```

Comment: Try with `//div[starts-with(text(),'Total (')][substring(text(),string-length(text()))=')']`

Comment: @supputuri Thanks. I will try that. But I would like to see if we can use regex aswell

Comment: Can you please share the part where you are actually trying to get the element (`$("...")`)

Comment: Regex is supported in XPATH 2.0. As far as I know, at the moment, browsers use XPATH 1.0, which does not support regex :(. I found this table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(XML)#Query_technologies) with query technology per browser engine. Hope it helps.